# displaying of parameter after selection in dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

if we select a value from dropdowlist e.g 1 or 2 etc. it should display number and size for a particular product. if we selected 2 from dropdownlist then number and size should display two times.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please be more specific about your question. Post code and clearly explain what you need to be done and most importantly **what you have tried so far**. Or else the question might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sample
ASPX

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="No. of Products:"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItems" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select-</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlItems.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int cntr=Convert.ToInt32(ddlItems.SelectedValue);

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SNO",typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ProductName",typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns["SNO"].AutoIncrement=true;
            dt.Columns["SNO"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;

            for(int i=1;i<=cntr;i++)
            {
                DataRow dr=dt.NewRow();
                dr["ProductName"]= " Sample Product Name for Item #"+ i;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource=dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```